# Confused about integration over zeroes.

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

Does for example $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(x) \, dx$ cancel out to zero (following WolframAlpha/normal integration technique), or do we have to take the absolute value of all the areas between bounds and zeroes (so in this case 4, which is how I learned it in school)?

Comment: As written, the integral is $0$.  The same would be true for $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\text dx$, since all areas above and below the $y=0$ line cancel.

Comment: For geometric intuition, it's helpful to think of the definite integral as **signed area** or **net area,** allowing for both positive and negative contributions that sometimes cancel each other out.

Comment: @SammyBlack So that is the canonical way of handling it?

Comment: It's what the definite integral *means.*  It's not just a way of handling it.

Comment: @SammyBlack Thank you.

Comment: If you actually want the area of the region bounded by a curve and the $x$-axis, then you need $\begin{align} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \lvert \sin x \rvert \, dx &= \int_{-\pi}^0 \lvert \sin x \rvert \, dx + \int_0^{\pi} \lvert \sin x \rvert \, dx \\ &= \int_{-\pi}^0 - \sin x \, dx + \int_0^{\pi} \sin x \, dx = -(-2) + (2) = 4 \end{align}$.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yeah right, I mistakenly inserted the result from the actual task.